# forEach auto layout Constraints not appearing

Tags: swift, for-loop, foreach, autolayout

My swifts code which uses a for loop to display to imageviews. Right now the code builds but nothing appears.  I know I have to move the leading anchor constraint over .25 for the second box. But I would think the first box which is box1 would appear but again nothing is appearing and i dont know why.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var box1 = UIButton();var box2 = UIButton()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        [box1,box2].forEach{
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.backgroundColor = .red
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            
            
            $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: $0.heightAnchor, multiplier: 30).isActive = true
            
            $0.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: $0.widthAnchor, multiplier: 30).isActive = true
            $0.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: $0.leadingAnchor ).isActive = true
            $0.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: $0.topAnchor).isActive = true

        }
    }
    
    
}
```

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L5B2.png)

Comment: How do you want the buttons to appear on screen? Add an example image.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you are trying to place the buttons in the view, because you haven't referred any view to the buttons that you're going to align to. Try below code & let me know if it works for you.

```
        $0.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        $0.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true

        $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        $0.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
```

Please note that, you were trying to set the height using '**multiplier**' instead of '**equalToConstant**'. Yes, you can use multiplier but only if you want to scale the image according to your parent view or any other view but in this case you need to set it to constant as you were giving a float value to it.

Comment: I added a photo of what I am looking for above in my question. thanks

Comment: Did above code worked for you? Did one button appeared on screen? @joebuck

Comment: the button appeared but only 1 button appeared

Comment: Yes, exactly. Your forEach loop will iterate through your views & will give exact same constraints to all the views that you're holding into your array. You have to give different constraints for different views. That is why only one button is appearing as the other button is lying behind the other.

Answer (score 0):

The below code the you're using doesn't make any sense. You're trying to add `leadingAnchor` and `topAnchor` of `box1` and `box2` to themselves.

```
$0.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: $0.leadingAnchor ).isActive = true
$0.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: $0.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

Instead you need to add the constraints to `self.view`

```
self.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: box1.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
box1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

Move the above code out of `forEach` loop.

And for `box2`, you need to update your problem statement with an image to clarify the layout of `box1` and `box2`.

Comment: I added a photo of what I am looking for above in my question. thanks